# How to change weather icon from json to a weather icon I drew myself

Tags: javascript, json, html, api, weather-api

I am trying to change the weather icons that I get from the API to the ones I have drawn myself on Photoshop! My variables are in french and the comments too, if you need translations to understand my code please ask!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            var maLatitude;     /*Variable gobale contenant la latitude*/
            var maLongitude;    /*Variable gobale contenant la longitude*/  

            if (navigator.geolocation)
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
            else
            alert("Votre navigateur supporte pas la géolocalisation, essayez de mettre à jour votre navigateur!");
        }); 

        function showPosition(position){
            maLatitude= position.coords.latitude;
            maLongitude= position.coords.longitude; 

        $.ajax({
            url : "http://api.wunderground.com/api/API_KEY/geolookup/conditions/lang:FC/q/"+maLatitude+","+maLongitude+".json",
            dataType : "jsonp",
            success : function(parsed_json) {

                var location = parsed_json['location']['city'];
                var temp_c = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_c'];  
                var tempRessentie = parsed_json['current_observation']['feelslike_c'];  
                var wicon = parsed_json['current_observation']['icon'];
                var condition = parsed_json['current_observation']['weather'];
                var vent_kmh = parsed_json['current_observation']['wind_kph'];
                var rafales = parsed_json['current_observation']['wind_gust_kph'];
                var visibilite = parsed_json['current_observation']['visibility_km'];

                $("div.ville").append("<div class='endroit'>" + location + " </div>"+
                                        "<div class='temp'>" + temp_c + " °C</div>"+
                                        "<div> Temp. ressentie : "+tempRessentie+" °C</div>"+
                                        "<div class='triangle'></div>"+
                                        "<div class='icone'><img src='http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/"+wicon+".gif' alt='"+condition+"' title='"+condition+"'/></div>"+
                                        "<div class='condition'>"+condition+"</div>"+
                                        "<div>Vent : "+vent_kmh+" km/h</div>"+
                                        "<div>Rafales : "+rafales+" km/h</div>"+
                                        "<div>Visibilité : "+visibilite+" km</div>");
                }
        }); 
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: So what's the question? Just change the `img` `src` to whatever you want.

Comment: But if I change it to another src it would only give me one specific weather icon, unless there's another way of doing it I didn't think of? :O

Comment: Basically depending on the weather of the day, there's a different weather icon that appears when loading the page! But I drew a few weather icon myself and I want to be able to load them depending on the weather of the day!

Comment: You need to have the same filenames as them or else map them yourself to whatever you want to use. So if they have `sunny.gif` you have `sunny.gif` and the only part you change is the path to your server.

Comment: OH YEAH THANKS ALOT!!! that worked! :D:D:D:D:D I can't express how happy I am!! thank you thank you thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So right here:

```
 "<div class='icone'><img src='http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/"+wicon+".gif' alt='"+condition+"' title='"+condition+"'/></div>"
```

Change it to:

```
 "<div class='icone'><img src='http://YourServer.com/yourIcons/"+ wicon +".gif' alt='"+condition+"' title='"+condition+"'/></div>"
```

And make sure you icons are named the same as they have.

Now, if you insist on having different names, you'll need to map their names to your names, which should be fairly trivial.

Comment: Be aware of what might happen if you haven't created replacements for **all** the icons. I would recommend adding a little more logic to only do the above if the icon name is one you recognise.

Comment: @Snixtor: what *might* happen is a broken link icon. Hardly the end of the world. But yes, if I was doing this I'd add a lot more logic around it to map conditions I know about to icons I have and just leave out the icon altogether if I don't recognize it. I'd also make sure I key-off something that I consider to be more stable than the filename of their icon because it could change. But that all seemed a bit over-the-head of the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Create an object an put the url for each of the weather icons into the object with a name representing the weather condition, then get the correct url by using the correct name:

```
var weatherIcons = {
   snowy:"/snowyicon.jpg",
   rainy:"/rainyicon.jpg",
   sunny:"/sunnyicon.jpg"
};

...

var condition = parsed_json['current_observation']['weather'];
var iconTOUse = weatherIcons[condition];

var element = '<img src="'+iconTOUse+'" />';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const weather = response.weather;

  if (weather === "Clear") {
    weatherIcon.src = "sun.png";
  } else if (weather === "Clouds") {
    weatherIcon.src = "cloud.png";
  } else if (weather === "Rain") {
    weatherIcon.src = "rain.png";
  } else {
    weatherIcon.src = "default.png";
  }

  console.log(response);
})
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```